# Tensorflow: LSTM with moving average of weights of another LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, moving-average, lstm

I would like to have an LSTM in tensorflow whose weights are the exponential moving average of the weights of another LSTM. So basically I have this code with some input placeholder and some initial state placeholder:

```
def test_lstm(input_ph, init_ph, scope):
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(128, use_peepholes=True)
        input_ph = tf.transpose(input_ph, [1, 0, 2])
        input_list = tf.unpack(input_ph)

        with tf.variable_scope(scope) as vs:
            outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(cell, input_list, initial_state=init_ph)

        theta = [v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]

        return outputs, theta

lstm_1, theta_1 = test_lstm(input_1, state_init_1, scope="lstm_1")
```

What I would like to do now is something similar along these lines (which don't actually work because the exponential moving average puts the tag "ema" behind the variable name of the weights and they do not appear in variable scope because they were not created with tf.get_variable):

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=1-self.tau, name="ema")

with tf.variable_scope("lstm_2"):
        maintain_averages_theta_1 = ema.apply(theta_1)
        theta_2_1 = [ema.average(x) for x in theta_1]

lstm_2 , theta_2_2 = test_lstm(input_2, state_init_2, scope="lstm_2"
```

where eventually theta_2_1 would be equal to theta_2_2 (or throw an exception because the variables already exist).

Answer (score 2):

- Change (3/May/2018): I added one line apart from the old answer. The old one itself is self-sufficient to this question, but it real practice we initialize 'target network' as the same value to the 'behavioural network'. I added this point. Search the line having 'Change0': You need to do this only once right after when the target network's parameters are just initialized. Without 'Change0', you first round of gradient-based update would become nasty since Q_target and Q_behaviour are not correlated while you need both to be somewhat related ex) TD = r + gamma*Q_target - Q_behaviour for the update.

Seems a bit late but hope this helps.
The critical problem of TF-RNN series possess is that we cannot directly designate the variables for RNNs unlike plain feedforward or convolutional NNs, so that we can't do simple work - get EMAed vars and plug into the network.

Let's go into the real deal(I attached a practice code to look-up for this, so please refer [EMA_LSTM.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzxiDcBmvq-IeWxBdXl2aFhWaUE)).

Shall we say, there is a network function containing LSTM:

```
def network(in_x,in_h):
   # Input: 'in_x' is the input sequence, 'in_h' is the initial hidden cell(c,m)
   # Output: 'hidden_outputs' is the output sequence(c-sequence), 'net' is the list of parameters used in this network function
   cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3, state_is_tuple=True)
   in_h = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(in_h[0], in_h[1])
   hidden_outputs, last_tuple = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, in_x, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=in_h)
   net = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if tf.contrib.framework.get_name_scope() in v.name]
   return hidden_outputs, net
```

Then you declare tf.placeholder for the necessary inputs, which are:

```
in_x = tf.placeholder("float", [None,None,6])
in_c = tf.placeholder("float", [None,3])
in_m = tf.placeholder("float", [None,3])
in_h = (in_c, in_m)
```

Lastly, we run a session that proceeds the network() function with specified inputs:

```
init_cORm = np.zeros(shape=(1,3))
input = np.ones(shape=(1,1,6))

print '========================new-1(beh)=============================='
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    with tf.variable_scope('beh', reuse=False) as beh:
        result, net1 = network(in_x,in_h)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        list = sess.run([result, in_x, in_h, net1], feed_dict={
            in_x : input,
            in_c : init_cORm,
            in_m : init_cORm
        })
    print 'result:', list[0]
    print 'in_x:' , list[1]
    print 'in_h:', list[2]
    print 'net1:', list[3][0][0][:4]
```

Now, we are going to make the var_list called 'net4' that contains the ExponentialMovingAverage(EMA)-ed values of 'net1', as in below with original 'net1' being first assigned in beh session above and newly assigned in below by adding 1. for each element:

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)
target_update_op = ema.apply(net1)
init_new_vars_op = tf.initialize_variables(var_list=[v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'ExponentialMovingAverage' in v.name]) # 'initialize_variables' will be replaced with 'variables_initializer' in 2017
sess.run(init_new_vars_op)
sess.run([param4.assign(param1.eval()) for param4, param1 in zip(net4,net1)]) # Change0

len_net1 = len(net1)
net1_ema = [[] for i in range(len_net1)]
for i in range(len_net1):
    sess.run(net1[i].assign(1. + net1[i]))

sess.run(target_update_op)
```

Note that

- we only initialised(by declaring 'init_new_vars_op' then running the declaration job) the variables of their name containing 'ExponentialMovingAverage', if not the variables in net1 will also be newly initialised.
- 'net1' is newly assigned with +1 for every elements of the variables in 'net1'. If an element of 'net1' was -0.5 and is now 0.5 by +1, then we want to have 'net4' as 0. when the EMA decay rate is 0.5
- Finally, we run the EMA job with 'sess.run(target_update_op)'

Eventually, we **declare 'net4' first** with the 'network()' function and then assign&run the EMA(net1) values into 'net4'. When you run 'sess.run(result)', then it will be the one with EMA(net1)-ed variables.

```
with tf.variable_scope('tare', reuse=False) as tare:
    result, net4 = network(in_x,in_h)
    len_net4 = len(net4)

    target_assign = [[] for i in range(len_net4)]
    for i in range(len_net4):
        target_assign[i] = net4[i].assign(ema.average(net1[i]))
        sess.run(target_assign[i].op)
    list = sess.run([result, in_x, in_h, net4], feed_dict={
        in_x : input,
        in_c : init_cORm,
        in_m : init_cORm
    })
```

What's happened in here? You just indirectly declares the LSTM variables as 'net4' in the 'network()' function. Then in the for loop, we **points out** that 'net4' is actually EMA of 'net1' and 'net1+1.' . Lastly, with the net4 specified what to do with(via 'network()') and what values it takes(via 'for loop of .assign(ema.average()) to itself'), you run the process.

It is somewhat counter-intuitive that we declare the 'result' first and specifies the value of parameters second. However, that's the nature of TF what they exactly look for, as it is always logical to set variables, processes, and their relation first then to assign values, then runs the processes.

Lastly, few things to go further for the real machine learning codes:

- In here, I just second assigned 'net1' with 'net1 + 1.'. In real case, this '+1.' step is where you 'sess.run()'(after you 'declare' in somewhere) your optimiser. So every-time after you 'sess.run(optimiser)', 'sess.run(target_update_op)' and then'sess.run(target_assign[i].op)' should follow to update your 'net4' along the EMA of 'net1'. Conceretly, you can do this job with different order like below:

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)
target_update_op = ema.apply(net1)

with tf.variable_scope('tare', reuse=False) as tare:
    result, net4 = network(in_x,in_h)
    len_net4 = len(net4)
    target_assign = [[] for i in range(len_net4)]
    for i in range(len_net4):
        target_assign[i] = net4[i].assign(ema.average(net1[i]))

init_new_vars_op = tf.initialize_variables(var_list=[v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'ExponentialMovingAverage' in v.name]) # 'initialize_variables' will be replaced with 'variables_initializer' in 2017
sess.run(init_new_vars_op)
sess.run([param4.assign(param1.eval()) for param4, param1 in zip(net4,net1)]) # Change0
```

Lastly, be aware that you must sess.run(ema.**apply**(net)) right after the net changes, and then sess.run(net_ema.assign(ema.average(net)). W/O .apply, net_ema will not get assigned with averaged value

```
len_net1 = len(net1)
net1_ema = [[] for i in range(len_net1)]
for i in range(len_net1):
    sess.run(net1[i].assign(1. + net1[i]))
sess.run(target_update_op)

for i in range(len_net4):
    sess.run(target_assign[i].op)
list = sess.run([result, in_x, in_h, net4], feed_dict={
    in_x : input,
    in_c : init_cORm,
    in_m : init_cORm
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. In fact, it is a bit too late as I was looking into this during my Master's thesis (which was on Deep RL). Would definitely be interested in your implementation, though.